# Remove everything after any digit in a pattern

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I am trying to use `gsub` to remove every character after any digit in each of the values of a column of my dataframe:

```
Tumoral_stage   Methastatic_stage
    T1a                M0
    T1b                M0
    T2c                M0
    T3b                M0
    T1c                M0
    T2                 M0
    T3a                M1
```

I would like to get this dataframe:

```
Tumoral_stage   Methastatic_stage
    T1                 M0
    T1                 M0
    T2                 M0
    T3                 M0
    T1                 M0
    T2                 M0
    T3                 M1
```

I would like to apply a `gsub` instruction in order to achieve this, but I don't know how to indicate to remove everything after **any** numeric character.

Comment: What about `T1a2b`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `sub()` and *positive lookbehind*:

```
x <- c("T1a", "T1b", "T2c", "T3b", "T1c", "T2", "T3a")

sub("(?<=[0-9]).+", "", x, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "T1" "T1" "T2" "T3" "T1" "T2" "T3"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `substr`

```
substr(x, 1, 2)
```

---

Or with `str_remove`

```
library(stringr)
str_remove(x, "[^0-9]+$")
```

#### data

```
x <- c("T1a", "T1b", "T2c", "T3b", "T1c", "T2", "T3a")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider capturing the part you want to keep and using backreference `\\1`:

```
sub("(.*\\d)\\w", "\\1", x)
[1] "T1" "T1" "T2" "T3" "T1" "T2" "T3"
```